# How can I enable Users to only edit their own data in Keystone.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, keystone

In Keystone.js, all admin users can view and change any data about other users, but I would like to have some hierarchy, so there is a root user group that can change anything about any user (except password) and a simple admin group that can see the dashboard but can't change information about other admin or root users.
How is that possible? I have to edit some routes in the keystone module, right? What are the best practices for that?